# Error al pintar el eje Y de un plot

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo una duda con un plot en Python.

Tengo que pintar en el eje X el porcentaje de batería de un aparato, es decir, rango de 0 a 100, y me gustaría dividirlo de diez en diez.

El código es el siguiente:

```
times = np.arange(np.datetime64(fecha1),
        np.datetime64(fecha2), np.timedelta64(salto, 'm'))
y = np.arange(datos.valor.min(), datos.valor.max(), 10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,6))
ax.plot(times, y)
plt.ylabel("Batería (%)")
plt.xlabel("Fecha")
```

Y el error es el siguiente:

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (96,) and (1024,)

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Ese es problema de tus datos, los cuales no sabemos.

Comment: hola @Christian comparto un enlace en csv con los datos, para que os hagaís una idea!  https://github.com/AitorLopez/Stackoverflow.git

Answer (score 0):

El error te indica que los conjuntos de datos entre gados al metodo plot como argumentos ,tienen diferente cantidad de elementos.
En este caso, las variable times y "y" tienen diferente cantidad de elementos. times tiene 94 y Y tiene 1024 por lo que el metodo plot no es capaz de generar una grafica con datos desapareados.
Para corregir esto debes entregar conjunto de datos con la misma cantidad de elementos.
por ejemplo

```
times = np.arange(np.datetime64(fecha1),
        np.datetime64(fecha2), np.timedelta64(salto, 'm'))
y = np.arange( 96)  #aqui esta la omdificacion

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,6))
ax.plot(times, y)
plt.ylabel("Batería (%)")
plt.xlabel("Fecha")
```

el link que compartiste a github esta caido